# getting multiple answers for reversing of a number python

Tags: python-3.x

```
num=int(input("enter a number:" ))
a=0
while (num>0):
    b=num%10
    a=a*10+b
    num=num//10
    print("reverse of num", "is", a)
```

this is the code , I want to reverse a number, but when I enter a number and press enter I receive multiple answers, and the last answer is the only one I want to get.[here is a pic for the problem I am having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjEHX.png)

Comment: Or `str` way like this - `int(str(x)[::-1])`  For learning - this is a great platform to try out https://pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 1):

Just put the print statement outside the while

```py
num=int(input("enter a number:" ))
a=0
while (num>0):
    b=num%10
    a=a*10+b
    num=num//10
print("reverse of num", "is", a)
```

Comment: thank you , I was confused for hours

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score -1):

You can easily solve this if you don't (immidiatly) convert the number to an int.

```
num = input("enter a number:" )
reversed_num = int(num[::-1])
print("reverse of num", "is", reversed_num)
```